# Customer session loggedIn() not working Magento 2

Tags: magento2, session, customer-session

I have to check whether a customer is logged in or not.
It only works for `My account page` and for the rest of the pages, it gives a null result. It was working before.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
$customerSession->isLoggedIn();
```

This code only works for My Account page, and for all other pages, it gives the empty result.

I tried this in my `header.phtml` as I need loggedIn condition in my `header.phtml` but it doesn't work.

```
 $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $context = $om->get('Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context');
 $isLoggedIn = $context->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
```

Still, this doesn't work in my `header.phtml`

What the issue, how to resolve it.

Comment: it's FPC issue. Please check after disabling Full Page Cache  and clearing cache it will work

Comment: @RutveeSojitra then why Full Page cache didn't affect My account page

Comment: please check https://mirasvit.com/blog/common-issues-and-few-hacks-with-magento-2-full-page-cache.html

Cacheable or Uncacheable

Comment: if you want to do your task with FPC you have https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/private-content.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create a module with helper method.

In Vendor/Module/Helper/Data.php,

```php
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
     */
    private $httpContext;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
    ) {
       $this->httpContext = $httpContext;                
       parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function isLoggedIn()
    {
        $isLoggedIn = $this->httpContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
        return $isLoggedIn;
    }

}
```

In your .phtml file, you can call like this:

```php
$custom_helper = $this->helper('Vendor\Module\Helper\Data');

var_dump($custom_helper->isLoggedIn());
```